# Resetting SelectedItem on a Listbox bound to a RelayCommand on a ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, relaycommand

Using the EventToCommand behaviour that comes with MVVM Light I am binding the SelectedItem of a ListBox to a RelayCommand on a ViewModel

All works great in my Windows Phone 7 app except that after navigating away from the View with the ListBox then back the SelectedItem is the same as before. Not what I want.

I tried reseting the selected index when navigating away but that causes the Command to trigger again.

Has anyone else solved this issue and how?

TIA

Patrick Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched away from using the SelectionChanged event. Now I do it all with TapGestures. Downside of this is that TapGesture does not work with EventToCommand behaviour so I am trapping the Gesture event in the View and firing the Command that is bound to the DataContext of the Sender.

IMHO this is a lot neater than using SelctionChanged and mucking about with SelectedIndexes.

Answer (score 1):

I handle this by a simple check at the start of each handler. Assuming that you are only supporting the single selection of items you can check if there is an added item.

```
if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

(Where `e` is an instance of `SelectionChangedEventArgs`.)

If the selection has been removed the `AddedItems` list will be empty but the `RemovedItems` list will be populated instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using mvvm light can't you call the clear method in the ViewModelLocator for the specific view model?